# changing the header picture of my webpages

Tags: php, image, header

i need to change the picture on header of my web page but the image path is not seen in header.php file. i tried changing it in the css sub file but it is not showing any change. i even deleted the old picture from the images folder in my XAMP folder but still the old picture is there. 
i'm new to php coding so please do suggest a solution

Comment: Welcome To StackOverflow please read this link before using this site https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please delete the browser cache. everything will work.